# Android:How to convert HttpResponse to List<Object>

Tags: java, android, json, rest, arraylist

I have android AsynTask method that call the Web Service which returns the List<> as shown below:

```
[[1,"Test",37.334542,-121.890821,-121.890821],
[2,"XYZ",37.337749,-121.886702,-121.886702],
[4,"PQR",37.336453,-121.884985,-121.884985]]
```

Here my question is how can I convert the response of HttpResponse to List<> as same as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a json response. If it is, the easiest way to do it if you have that String (jsonResponse) already is something like:

```
JSONArray json;
try {
    json = new JSONArray (jsonResponse);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    //do something
}
```

You can then just use the JSONArray as is, or iterate through it and add each item to a `List` if you need.

Comment: Hey Mike I am able to get jsonArray from jsonResponse by above method and when I print jsonArray.get(0) it prints [1,"Test",37.334542,-121.890821,-121.890821] but I am not able to get individual value like 1 or test. Can you please tell me how can I get it?

Comment: Sure. What you have is a `JSONArray` of JSONArrays. So, `jsonArray.get(0)` will return another JSONArray (call it innerArray). Then you can use `innerArray.get(0)` to get the first number. I hope that helps :)